# Filter out few lines from tail -f of the file

Tags: linux, shell, sh

I have a log of some programm. I'm running `tail -f` on it and I want to show all except of some exception so I guess it's some use of

```
tail -f logfile.log | grep <something>
```

The thing is that I want to hide not only one string but 10 lines after it that is stacktrace of the exception.
How can I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed you can use `sed /pattern/,+10d` to delete 10 lines after the pattern as well as the line containing the pattern.

```
tail -f logfile.log | sed /pattern/,+10d
```